# How Angular $watch should work on arrays

Tags: angularjs, sockets, watch

Sorry for being Naive but new to AngularJs.

I have this application where the server is sending a socket event which is listened by the frontEnd angular application.
As the socket sends the data, I am pushing the new data to an Array which is watched by $scope.$watch().

But I see the "Error" is being printed out but not "it Happened again !!". even though the array is being watched.

Please guide me and let me know what am I doing wrong in here ?

```
app.controller('errorCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, socket){
  $scope.errorList=[];
  $scope.$watch('errorList', function(){
    console.log('it Happened again !!');
  });
  socket.on('error', function(data){
    $timeout(function(){
      console.log('Error');
      $scope.errorList.push(data);  
    },0);
    console.log($scope.errorList);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change to use watchCollection

```
  $scope.$watchCollection('errorList', function(newValues, oldValues){

  });
```

see docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Comment: Worked like a charm, Also Thanks for pointing out to the right direction.